# Prevent Simple Injector to throw an exception when resolving an unregistered service

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

I was wondering if Simple Injector has an option to stop throwing exceptions whenever `GetInstance(Of TService)` returns `Nothing`?  It appears to be throwing them now because I have two requests to get an instance, it's not there, and it throws the exception.

Is there a way to prevent the default behavior, a setting somewhere, or something else?

Comment: Are you sure returning `Nothing` is a valid situation? It is often better return a [Null Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) instead of returning `null`. This can also save you from having to call the container from within your application.

Comment: Yes, in this scenario, Nothing is best to be returned because a follow up statement checks and loads from another source.  This is defined within a third-party toolset, so I have no control over that conditional logic.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There absolutely is a simple way of doing this. The `SimpleInjector.Container` implements [System.IServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iserviceprovider.aspx), which defines an [object GetService(Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iserviceprovider.getservice.aspx) method. This method returns `null` when a type is not registered. The `IServiceProvider` however, is implemented explicitly, which means it doesn't show up under normal use, so you have to cast the `Container` to `IServiceProvider`, as shown below:

```
IServiceProvider provider = container;
object instance = provider.GetService(typeof(MyClass));
```

Or you can define an extension method on top of this:

```
public static bool TryGetInstance<TService>(
    this Container container, out TService instance)
    where TService : class
{
    IServiceProvider provider = container;
    instance = (TService)provider.GetService(typeof(TService));
    return instance != null;
}
```

I must admit that this feature is a bit hidden. The only place [this method](https://simpleinjector.org/ReferenceLibrary/?topic=html/M_SimpleInjector_Container_System_IServiceProvider_GetService.htm) is currently explained is in the reference library.

Do note that in general it is much better to register [Null Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) implementations (empty implementations without any behavior) instead of calling an `TryGetInstance` method. Injecting Null Objects prevents the application from having to worry about null references, which makes your application code easier to understand and easier to test.

Comment: Is there any updates on this in the new versions? Also the link to the reference library is broken and I couldn't find the new one.

Comment: @mrmashal nothing has changed in v3 this respect.

Comment: Upvote for suggesting registering NULL if not needed. Simply, if you inject in a constructor, then make the parameter optional ( = null)

Comment: Hi Alex, I'm afraid you misinterpreted my answer. A Null Object is a design pattern which means an empty implementation. You should not make constructor arguments for injected services optional and never allow `null` to be injected. That leads to extra complexity in the consumer. Instead the registration and injection of a dummy implementation (the Null Object pattern) provides a better solution.