# ServiceStack is IRequestLogger necessary?

Tags: c#, servicestack

In the service stack configuration I'm getting an error "No registration for type IRequestLogger could be found." with the default configuration, after looking around it looks that I need to add a a pluging like in the configuration.

```
Plugins.Add(new RequestLogsFeature { RequiredRoles = new string[] { } });
```

the question is why am I getting this error? and if necessary to define the IRequestLogger.

I'm using Simple Injector as the IoC Container.

Edit:
this is my IoC Code:

```
 public override void Configure(Container container)
            { 

                var simpleInjector = new SimpleInjectorContainer();
                container.Adapter = simpleInjector;
                Plugins.Add(new RequestLogsFeature { RequiredRoles = new string[] { } });
                simpleInjector.SContainer.Register<ICacheClient, MemoryCacheClient>();
                simpleInjector.SContainer.Register<IUserRepository,UserRepository>();
                Routes.Add<UserRequest>("/Api/User/{Id}");

                //Routes.Add<HomeResponse>("/Api/Home","GET");

            }

     public class SimpleInjectorContainer:ISimpleInjectorContainer
        {

             public SimpleInjectorContainer()
             {
                 SContainer = new SimpleInjector.Container();
             }

             public SimpleInjector.Container SContainer { get; set; }

             public T TryResolve<T>()
             {

                 return (T)SContainer.GetInstance(typeof(T));
             }

             public T Resolve<T>()
             {
                 return (T)SContainer.GetInstance(typeof(T));
             }
        }

         public interface ISimpleInjectorContainer : IContainerAdapter
        {
             SimpleInjector.Container SContainer { get; set; }
        }
```

thanks.

Comment: Request Logger is a completely optional plugin. It should not throw any exceptions. Can you show your apphost and IOC code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your TryResolve implementation more forgiving. It needs to be able to handle not being able to resolve the Service. If IRequestLogger resolves to null then ServiceStack will simply skip it.

**Resolve** should require the interface be registered.
**TryResolve** should gracefully handle the interface not being registered.

See this SO answer for how to do this [Prevent Simple Injector to throw an exception when resolving an unregistered service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10076523/215502)

Comment: interesting I thought that what it was causing the problem was the serviceStack, but your answer totally make sense, thanks!